# How to disable or purge non-class types in tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, rollupjs

So on my project, I want to run a svelte bundle (using rollup) inside a PHP and use tailwindcss to configure the classes of that bundle.

The problem is that I didn't know tailwind does a lot of element selector styling (body, h1, table etc.) and the PHP project already has css files that has default selector style that I plan to use.

Is their a way to ignore all of the selector style in tailwindcss or a way to make it isolated within the bundle (the bundle is being loaded inside a div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element selector rules are from [Tailwind's preflight core plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight). [As per the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight), you can disable it like any other core plugin, in `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
}
```